# How to get the list of docs that exist more than 1 time in mongoDB with the same field?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-shell

I would like to create a query that will get all the docs with title that exist more than 1 time in mongoDB.

lets say that this is my doc:

```
{
  "itemID" : "AAN88998JJCA",
  "itemTitle" : "AAAA
}

{
  "itemID" : "AAN8BB98JJCA",
  "itemTitle" : "AAAA"
}

{
  "itemID" : "A5N84998JJ3A",
  "itemTitle" : "AACC"
}

{
  "itemID" : "A2N81998JJC1",
  "itemTitle" : "AACC"
}

{
  "itemID" : "A2N81998JJC1",
  "itemTitle" : "BBBB"
}
```

I would like to set a query that will produce a list of

```
 {
      "itemID" : "AAN88998JJCA",
      "itemTitle" : "AAAA
    }

    {
      "itemID" : "AAN8BB98JJCA",
      "itemTitle" : "AAAA"
    }

    {
      "itemID" : "A5N84998JJ3A",
      "itemTitle" : "AACC"
    }

    {
      "itemID" : "A2N81998JJC1",
      "itemTitle" : "AACC"
    }
```

Which mean a record with the same title that exist in the DB more than 1 time.
I can do it in Java code but seem like it would be more reasonable to do it on the DB level.

Comment: Your query result has objects with different itemTitles

Comment: @JamesB thats true, this is what i want to get from the DB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using aggregation framework, you can group `itemTitle` by the number of occurences:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$itemTitle",
            total: { $sum: 1 }
        }
    }
    ,{
        $match: {
            total: { $gt: 1 }
        }
    }
]);
```